# jQuery css('padding') - Issue with Firefox

Tags: jquery, css, firefox, padding

It seems Firefox (at least v19.0.2) has an issue with jQuery [css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) function, when you try to get an element's `padding`.

I don't have the problem when I use `.css('padding-left')`, but it would be nice to write a single line instead of 4, particularly on a simple feature like this one.

Here's a sample to show my problem, please compare Chrome/Firefox behaviors:

```js
$('#log').append(
    'padding : '+        $('#sample').css('padding')+'\n'+
    'padding-top : '+    $('#sample').css('padding-top')+'\n'+
    'padding-bottom : '+ $('#sample').css('padding-bottom')+'\n'+
    'padding-left : '+   $('#sample').css('padding-left')+'\n'+
    'padding-right : '+  $('#sample').css('padding-right')+'\n'
);
```

```css
#sample {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 8px;
    margin: 10px;
}
#log {
    padding: 8px;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sample">Lorem ipsum</div>
<textarea id="log" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
```

Am I missing anything ? Or is there a workaround to retrieve an element's `padding` without calling 4 functions ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

See [bug #13421](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13421) (although this is not actually a bug).

The documentation for [css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) says:

> Shorthand CSS properties (e.g. `margin`, `background`, `border`) are not
>   supported. For example, if you want to retrieve the rendered margin,
>   use: `$(elem).css('marginTop')` and `$(elem).css('marginRight')`, and so
>   on.

`padding` is such a property, so you will indeed have to use `paddingLeft`, `paddingRight`, etc.