# Padding Chrome vs. Firefox

Tags: jquery, css

```
var diff = $(this.wrapper).find('div.options').height();
$(this.wrapper).find('#messages').css({paddingBottom: diff});
```

this is in Chrome:

[image]

and this is in Firefox:

In both cases the padding is calculated, but firefox don't recognize it

Comment: [See this StackOverFlow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15497246/jquery-csspadding-issue-with-firefox) This might be what is causing your issue.

Comment: Do you also have a screen shot from Firefox?